# Full row selection is not working properly after cellpainting event used for drawing a image in a datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

When I tried to select full row in datagridview, the last column's cell background color is not changing. That last cell has a image which drawn by using cellpainting method. How to select the Full row under these circumstance.

[image]

```
private void dgvMobileOperators_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 8 && dgvMobileOperators.Rows[e.RowIndex ].Cells[e.ColumnIndex+1].Value.ToString()=="1"  /*&& Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) == 1*/)
             {
                 e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                 dgvMobileOperators[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                 PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                 // p.X += imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
                 p.X += 24;
                 // string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EasySMPP\App\Images\sms.ico");
                 string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\Images\\connect_established.png";
                 e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 73, 18);
                 e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
                 e.Handled = true;
             }
            else if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 8 && dgvMobileOperators.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex +1].Value.ToString() == "0"/*&& Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) == 0*/)
             {
                 e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                 dgvMobileOperators[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                 PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                 // p.X += imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
                 p.X += 24;
                 // string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EasySMPP\App\Images\sms.ico");
                 string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\Images\\connect_no.png";
                 e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 73, 18);
                 e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
                 e.Handled = true;
             }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Close. But this:

```
 e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
```

tells it to **not** display the selection.

Instead use:

```
 e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I checked with a if condition that current row is selected and not, after I change images for the conditions. Finally added 2 images are with selected background color

```
 private void dgvMobileOperators_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvMobileOperators.SelectedRows[0].Index != e.RowIndex)
            {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 8 && dgvMobileOperators.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Value.ToString() == "1"  /*&& Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) == 1*/)
                {
                    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                    dgvMobileOperators[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                    PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                    // p.X += imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
                    p.X += 24;
                    // string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EasySMPP\App\Images\sms.ico");
                    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\Images\\connect_established.png";
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 79,23);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 8 && dgvMobileOperators.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Value.ToString() == "0"/*&& Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) == 0*/)
                {
                    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                    dgvMobileOperators[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                    PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                    // p.X += imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
                    p.X += 24;
                    // string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EasySMPP\App\Images\sms.ico");
                    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\Images\\connect_no.png";
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 79, 23);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 8 && dgvMobileOperators.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Value.ToString() == "1"  /*&& Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) == 1*/)
                {
                    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                    dgvMobileOperators[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                    PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                    // p.X += imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
                    p.X += 24;
                    // string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EasySMPP\App\Images\sms.ico");
                    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\Images\\connect-ok.png";
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 79, 23);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 8 && dgvMobileOperators.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Value.ToString() == "0"/*&& Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) == 0*/)
                {
                    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                    dgvMobileOperators[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                    PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                    // p.X += imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
                    p.X += 24;
                    // string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EasySMPP\App\Images\sms.ico");
                    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\Images\\connect-fail.png";
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 79, 23);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }



        }
```